# How to rececive an object in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

getting an error when I try to receive object in a component.

In console log "react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, url, icon}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
`this is data component when some id, url, ann icon I can't pass those data to Navbar component`

```
export const social = [
  {
   id: 1,
   url: 'https://www.twitter.com',
   icon: <FaTwitter />,
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   url: 'https://www.facebook.com',
   icon: <FaFacebook />,
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   url: 'https://www.linkein.com',
   icon: <FaLinkedin />,
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   url: 'https://www.youtube.com',
   icon: <FaYoutube />,
  },
];
```

`I added some data in the data component in console there showing Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, url, icon})`

```
import React from 'react';
import { social } from './data';
const Navbar = () => {
  console.log(social);
  return (
    <nav>
      <div>
        {social.map((item: any, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
        })}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

`but without typescript  variant I can receive all those data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot render raw objects in JSX, you have to shape them somehow, for instance:

```
type Social = {
  id: number;
  url: string;
  icon: ReactNode;
}

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      {social.map(({ id, url, icon }: Social) => (
        <li key={id}>
          <a href={url}>{icon}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
};
```